# Data encryption during transit from s3 to onpremise server

Tags: amazon-s3, encryption

How can we make sure that data transfer from S3 to on-premise server using aws cli will be protected/encrypted.

Answer (score 0):

By default the aws cli tools are using the https protocol, so the transport is encrypted. You don't need to do anything.

If you want to be really sure, you can explicitly define the S3 service endpoint using the [--endpoint-url](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/#options) option and specify an explicit [endpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/s3.html) with the *https* protocol